# Passing different data to same name json attribute in retrofit model

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

There is a WebService which i want to @GET and @POST data from it, but all of its responses are like this theme:

```
 {
  "data": {
    ...
  },
  "success": ... ,
  "message": ...
}
```

but there are different output themes of **data**, like these:

```
{
  "data": {
    "update_status": "critical",
    "last_version_name": "1.0.3",
    "last_version_code": "3",
    "need_to_upgrade": false
  },
  "success": true,
  "message": "DONE!"
}
```

&

```
{
  "data": {
    "year": "2020",
    "month": "09",
    "day": "09",
    "hour": "06",
    "second": "00",
    "unix": "1599631246"
  },
  "success": true,
  "message": null
}
```

How can i define models to use this via Retrofit and GSON Converter?
Should i use @SerializedName somewhere?

(i.e:)

```
public class Response{
    private boolean success;
    private String message;
    
    //private Data data
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Base Contract and extend it by all of the response classes. in Contract `data` part will be Generic.

```
public class BaseResponse<T> {
public boolean success;
public String message;
public T data;
 }
```

Now you have to create data class for each type of response.

```
public class MyResponse{
public String update_status;
public String last_version_name;
public String last_version_code;
public boolean need_to_upgrade;
}
```

Now you can use `BaseResponse<MyResponse>` as return type of retrofit call. You can do the same for Array response i.e create a `BaseListResponse` class.